# why I couldn't access static property in getDerivedStateFromProps()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to React, just a question on access static property in getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle method, below is my code:

```
export default Child extends Component {
  static counter = 0
  ...
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
     if(counter = 1) {
         ...
     }
     a += 1;
  }

  render() {
     ...
  }
}
```

the error is

> 'counter' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: `if (this.counter === 1)`. Suggesting to close as typo.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `class name` to access it..

```
Child.counter
```

Example.

```
class Child extends Component {
  static counter = 0;

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    //"this" is undefined here
    console.log("this === " + this);
     if(Child.counter === 0) {
         console.log("counter is ", Child.counter);
     }
     return null;
  }

  render() {
     return "Hello"
  }
}
```

You can try the SO snippet below to see the console logs

```js
const {render} = ReactDOM

class Child extends React.Component {
  static counter = -123;
  
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    //this is undefined here
    console.log("this === " + this);
    console.log("counter is ", Child.counter);
    return null;
  }

  render() {
     return "Hello"
  }
}


render(<Child />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Also note that, as `getDerivedStateFromProps` is a static method, it won't have access to component instance.

The below article might help on when to use it.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state

Comment: @JordanRunning Thanks for the input. Deleted the stackblitz link and added a SO React snippet instead.